# Which parameter do I set on a lathe to use Notepad.exe as the program editor?

Tags: okuma

I'm trying to disable the "Quick-Edit" function programmatically via the API. Using the COptionalParameter class I can set Parameter 70 bit 7 to 1 on a mill which causes the machine to use Notepad.exe as the default program editor.  A handy side effect of this is that the "Quick-Edit" function is disabled. I want to do the same thing on a lathe but can't find which parameter needs to be set for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try No 63 bit 2.

If it doesn't work, the current OSP version is probably too low.

This is supported by NC 283L and greater.

Comment: FYI: This is supported by NC 283L or greater